# where to put a text file in xcode to be read in C++

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I'm using xcode version 6.2 to write my C++ program. I have a file entitled inventory.txt that I want my program to read. Where do I insert the text file?

The current path to where the main cpp is

```
Documents/xcode workspace/inventory/inventory/ main.cpp
```

and my project is located at

```
Documents/xcode workspace/inventory/inventory.xcodeproj
```

Comment: Inside Xcode there is an expandable directory on the left side where you can see all your project's source files. Drag your `inventory.txt` and drop it in the area called `Supporting Files` or similar.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I don't see "Supporting Files"

Comment: It's there in the pink Navigator area on the left...https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapOSX/books/RM_YourFirstApp_Mac/Articles/GettingStarted.html

Comment: @MarkSetchell i do see that but unfortunately i don't see anything similar to a supporting files =(

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have that same setup as the pink Navigator area, but I don't see where to drop it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a relative path, the easiest would be to put it in the same directory as the executable.

But you can also use an absolute path to the file.